# No puedo ver mi formulario

Tags: php, formularios

Estoy trabajando en una **página de registro de usuarios** en PHP.
Antes funcionaba, actualicé versión de xampp y ahora **no veo el formulario, no me deja un die de un if (!isset**. Antes del formulario y de que se envien los datos (en el top de la página PHP tengo un **código/comprobador** PHP que verifica si los datos han sido enviados o si los campos van vacíos y al parecer al abrir la página **se anticipa** y **me muestra el die de un if (!isset...** pongo el código a ver si me ayudáis, gracias.

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/prueba.php');?>
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Comprobar envío datos
if (!isset ($_POST['name'], 
$_POST['username'], 
$_POST ['password'], 
$_POST['email']))
{die('por favor rellene el formulario');}
//Verificar campos no vayan vacíos
if (empty ($_POST['name']) || empty
($_POST['username']) || empty 
($_POST['password']) || 
empty ($_POST['email']))
{die ('por favor rellene los campos');}
?>
```

y eso es lo que me imprime el navegador, lo que hay tras el die, es decir "por favor rellene el formulario".
¿Que falla?
Saludos.

Comment: @David JP es el sistema de escritura de aquí el que pone en Mayúsculas php, al menos desde Android.

Comment: Puedes agregar el html o php de tu registro, el código que agregaste según entiendo es el que valida los datos que recibe.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos últimas variables $POST en vez de $_POST.
No te dará ningún error porque estás precisamente comprobando si existen o no, pero a no ser que $POST lo generes previamente tú, ese if nunca será true.

Por otro lado, no creo que haber actualizado tenga relación. Prueba a cambiar eso a ver si te sale algún error.

Comment: Error mío al escribir el código aquí a mano, (ya lo edité) ; en la página estan bien todos las $_POST

Comment: deberías pegar el código original. En ese ejemplo que has puesto terminas la primera línea con ?> por lo que la segunda ya no se ejecutará en php sino que será texto plano enviado como html. No se puede saber qué pasa si no se ve lo que debe hacer.

Igualmente, si realmente esa es la segunda línea de código y asumiendo que sí se ejecuta correctamente, lo lógico es que termine en el die. Estás diciendo que si $_POST['...'] no existe (!isset) que lance el die. Cuando cargas la página no estás enviando ningún formulario. Yo separaría el controller por un lado y el html por otro.

Comment: Ya tienes todo el código del principio, espero te ayude a ayudarme, si necesitas más mañana entro al pc con conexión a Internet y te lo copió/pego, con smartphone es tedioso escribir, por eso reduje la introducción de tanto código, saludos.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, estaba usando una copia distinta del formulario que tenía, vamos estaba manejando otro formulario editado por decir así, gracias a todos.